# Spinner resets value after onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Spinner with a bunch of state names.  In onCreate, I set it to a default value.  The index 0 in the Spinner array is "Alabama"

```
String state = "California"; //preset to this

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_state_and_drivers_license);

    statesSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.states_spinner);
    adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>)statesSpinner.getAdapter();
    statesSpinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(state));

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RESULT_CAMERA);    
}
```

However, after onResult, the Spinner is once again set to "Alabama".  Meaning it reverts back to index 0 of the array, even though I thought it should keep its existing selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Try relocating this in the [onResume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) call.

Also use logcat to see if onCreate is being called.